# VBScript and sendkeys not working with DirectX?

Tags: vbscript, directx, sendkeys

I am playing GTA SA:MP. It uses DirectX, and if you are AFK on the server you get automatically kicked, and I would like to let it AFK on the server while I'm left. 
I tried creating a VBScript that automatically after 8 minutes presses W and then loops but it actually doesn't work. The player doesn't move.

Code:

```
Dim a
Dim antiafk


set antiafk=createobject("wscript.shell")

msgbox "Atentie! Ca sa opriti scriptul, trebuie sa il opriti NUMAI din Task Manager. Nu exista alta cale."

Do until a=5
wscript.sleep 480000
antiafk.sendkeys "w"
Loop
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Before doing this, you might want to check the EULA as AFK macros are not allowed in many games.

Answer (score 0):

`SendKeys` method sends one or more keystrokes **to the active window**. Use `AppActivate` method to activate your application window first.

The script is a simplified version of your one, with *no 8 minutes loop* and `notepad.exe` instead of your application name.

```
option explicit
On Error Goto 0

Dim antiafk
set antiafk=createobject("wscript.shell")

Dim lngPID, booSuccess, foo
lngPID = getlngPID()

If lngPID = 0 Then
    foo = antiafk.Popup( "No instance found", 5, _
                  "29445451", vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
Else
    booSuccess = antiafk.AppActivate( lngPID)
    If not booSuccess Then 
      foo = antiafk.Popup( "AppActivate Method unsuccesfull", 5, _
                    "29445451", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation) 
    Else
      antiafk.sendkeys "w"
    End If
End If

Function getLngPID()
  getLngPID = 0
  Dim strComputer
  Dim objWMIService, colProcessList, objProcess

  strComputer = "."
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
      & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

  Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
      ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Notepad.exe'") 

  'find appropriate and suitable Process ID
  For Each objProcess in colProcessList 
      getLngPID = objProcess.ProcessId
  Next 
End Function
```